# How do I download, install, and run Minecraft? As well as OpenJDK7?

Tags: installation, java, minecraft, opengl, openjdk

First off, I have tried downloading Minecraft.
I logged in, and the launcher did work.
But, when I tried to "play Demo",
this is what showed up:

#### Developer Console before clicking "Play Demo"

```
Refreshing local version list...
Launcher 1.2.2 (through bootstrap 5) started on linux...
Current time is Sep 11, 2013 8:04:23 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '3.8.0-30-generic'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_40'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'
Refreshing remote version list...
Refresh complete.
Loaded 2 profile(s); selected '(Default)'
Refreshing auth...
Logging in with access token
Delta time to compare resources: 831 ms 
Download job 'Resources' skipped as there are no files to download
Job 'Resources' finished successfully
```

#### After clicking "Play Demo"

```
Client> ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
Client> // Daisy, daisy...
Client> 
Client> Time: 9/11/13 8:10 PM
Client> Description: Initializing game
Client> 
Client> org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7f8a042f3e50 serial: 36 error: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation) request_code: 156 minor_code: 14
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:318)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:788)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
Client>     at ats.O(SourceFile:297)
Client>     at ats.d(SourceFile:599)
Client>     at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
Client> 
Client> 
Client> A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
Client> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Client> 
Client> -- Head --
Client> Stacktrace:
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:318)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:788)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
Client>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
Client>     at ats.O(SourceFile:297)
Client> 
Client> -- Initialization --
Client> Details:
Client> Stacktrace:
Client>     at ats.d(SourceFile:599)
Client>     at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
Client> 
Client> -- System Details --
Client> Details:
Client>     Minecraft Version: 1.6.2
Client>     Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.8.0-30-generic
Client>     Java Version: 1.6.0_27, Sun Microsystems Inc.
Client>     Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Sun Microsystems >Inc.
Client>     Memory: 1031430600 bytes (983 MB) / 1105395712 bytes (1054 MB) up to 1105395712 bytes (1054 MB)
Client>     JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xmx1100M -Xms1100M
Client>     AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
Client>     Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
Client>     IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
Client>     Launched Version: 1.6.2
Client>     LWJGL: 2.9.0
Client>     OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
Client>     Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
Client>     Type: Client (map_client.txt)
Client>     Resource Pack: Default
Client>     Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
Client>     Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Client>     Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
Client> #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# /home/kevinlin3100/.minecraft>/crash-reports/crash-2013-09-11_20.10.15-client.txt
Client> #
Client> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Client> #
Client> #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8a005c0ae8, pid=5020, tid=140230833391360
Client> #
Client> # JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
Client> # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Client> # Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
Client> # Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2
Client> # Problematic frame:
Client> # C  [libX11.so.6+0x33ae8]  XQueryExtension+0x28
Client> #
Client> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
Client> # /home/kevinlin3100/.minecraft/hs_err_pid5020.log
Client> #
Client> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
Client> # instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
Client> #   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
Client> #
Game ended with bad state (exit code 134)
Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
Deleting /home/kevinlin3100/.minecraft/versions/1.6.2/1.6.2-natives-4478207449754
```

I also want to know how to install tar.gz files. Google offers me no help. That is how I want to install OpenJDK7 x64. (ie from the Oracle Website).

I have Ubuntu 12.10 LTS.
The server works fine, and all its features. It's just the actual game that I'm worried about.

Comment: OpenJDK is not made by Oracle, they make Oracle Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can install openjdk7 from the Ubuntu Store, and right click on "Minecraft" and click run with OpenJDK7.